# Can not delete object from Parse Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server, mongodb-atlas

I can add, get or update objects in parse-server via SDKs or Parse Dashboard but can not delete it.

It gives this error when I try

```
ParseError: 1 Database adapter error
Error: Database adapter error
```

I migrate my DB from mLab to Mongo Atlas one month ago but I was able to delete my objects one week ago.

I checked my DB account's role and it has privilege to every action.

My current server config :

```
Package          Current   Wanted   Latest  Location
aws-sdk          2.713.0  2.726.0  2.726.0  parse-server-heroku
bad-words          1.6.5    1.6.5    3.0.3  parse-server-heroku
datauri            1.1.0    1.1.0    3.0.0  parse-server-heroku
express-graphql   0.6.12   0.6.12   0.11.0  parse-server-heroku
graphql           0.11.7   0.11.7   15.3.0  parse-server-heroku
jdenticon          1.8.0    1.8.0    3.0.1  parse-server-heroku
kerberos          0.0.23   0.0.23    1.1.3  parse-server-heroku
mongodb           2.2.36   2.2.36    3.6.0  parse-server-heroku
newrelic           2.9.1    2.9.1   6.11.0  parse-server-heroku
nodemon           1.19.4   1.19.4    2.0.4  parse-server-heroku
onesignal-node     2.1.1    2.1.1    3.1.5  parse-server-heroku
parse             1.10.2   1.10.2   2.15.0  parse-server-heroku
parse-server       2.7.2    2.7.2    4.3.0  parse-server-heroku
request-promise    4.2.5    4.2.6    4.2.6  parse-server-heroku
uuid               3.4.0    3.4.0    8.3.0  parse-server-heroku
xml2json          0.11.2   0.11.2   0.12.0  parse-server-heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Database adapter error` just means that the delete operation failed for some reason, but it won't tell you more than that. You have two options:

1. Look into the MongoDB logs in Atlas, you may have to change the MongoDB log level, more on that in the Atlas docs.
2. Debug Parse Server and set a breakpoint at the point where the error message appears to look at the original error response from MongoDB Atlas for more info.

In general, I suggest to upgrade Parse Server to the latest version, since a lot has happened since v2.7.2. Although I can't think of any breaking changes (other than MongoDB 3.6. is not officially supported anymore), it may solve the error.

Comment: Yes I believe you are right about old version of Parse. I would like to update it but it gives too much error when I try. Thanks for suggestions I will try !

Comment: Parse offers you a Migration Guide for how to update. Maybe that helps you. You can find it on GitHub.